# How to automatically look for index files with absolute path?

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I'm creating a new project with node.js, express.js and typescript.

I decided to use absolute paths, but I'm not very satisfied, because when I import files, it doesn't recognize automatically index.ts files.

**My folder structure:**

```
|--routes
|  |--index.ts
|  |--user.routes.ts
|--models
|  |--index.ts
|  |--user.ts
|--controllers
|  |--index.ts
|  |--user.controller.ts
|--services
|  |--index.ts
|  |--user.services.ts
|--index.ts
```

**And my imports are like:**

```
import { mainRouter } from '@routes/index';
```

**I wanted it like:**

```
import { mainRouter } from '@routes';
```

I read something about it, and said that absolute paths treats every file as a folder, that's why it happens.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: _"absolute paths treats every file as a folder"_ That's wrong. `@routes` isn't a path. You have an alias for it in your configuration. You can add the `index.ts` file to this configuration.